# Нужно тире или запятая?

Tags: запятые, тире

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно будет поставить тире в предложении или там нужна только запятая:
"Как только стоит выбор между тем, что сделать, что купить, что съесть, с кем общаться, — задайте себе вопрос: этот выбор я делаю из любви к себе?"

Answer (score 2):

*Как только стоит выбор между тем, **что сделать, что купить, что съесть, с кем общаться,** — задайте себе вопрос: этот выбор я делаю из любви к себе?*

Здесь ставится запятая и тире как единый знак по правилу Розенталя:http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=144#pp144

Запятая и тире в качестве единого знака препинания ставятся в сложноподчиненном предложении:

1. перед главной частью, которой предшествует **ряд однородных придаточных,** если подчеркивается распадение сложного предложения **на две части** (перед главной частью делается длительная пауза):
   Кто виноват из них, кто прав, — судить не нам (Кр.); Делал ли что-нибудь для этого Штольц, что делал и как делал, — мы этого не знаем (Добр.); Сколько их было всего, этих людей, пришли ли они сюда случайно, долго ли останутся здесь, — этого я вам сказать не могу;

Или: *Как только встает выбор между тем, **что сделать, что купить, что съесть, с кем общаться,** — спросите себя: этот выбор я делаю из любви к себе?*

Comment: Поддержал ответ. Буду благодарен, если скажете своё мнение по поводу запятой перед **или** в самой формулировке вопроса от Алисы: нужна там запятая или нет? Я бы поставил (по интонации), но правила для этого случая какие-то смутные, я их толком не понимаю.

Comment: Запятая вроде бы не ставится из-за вопросительной итононации:  Запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав в качестве частей входят:

1) вопросительные предложения: Это кто такие и что им надобно? (П.) — объединяет вопросительная интонация; Вы придёте ко мне или мне прийти к вам?;http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Comment: Запятая не ставится не только из-за вопросительных предложений, но и из-за того, что они односоставные.

Comment: Я не согласен по поводу схожести случаев, так как у Розенталя придаточные предшествуют главному, а в данном предложении придаточные вообще не относятся к последующему.

Comment: @Sharon *если подчеркивается распадение сложного предложения на две части* — то есть не всегда, здесь оно точно не подчёркивается. Можете прочитать об этом в комментариях здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467635. И перед ИЛИ лучше присоединение (запятая), без него звучит немного не по-русски.

Answer (score 1):

Уважаемые друзья! Мне задали так много вопросов, что я не знаю, с чего начать.  Некоторые из них вводят меня в глубокую задумчивость.

(1)  «Запятая не ставится не только из-за вопросительных предложений, но и из-за того, что они односоставные».   Розенталь говорит о том, что **вопросительная интонация** СВЯЗЫВАЕТ предложения в одну фразу. Она (эта интонация) вполне справляется со своей задачей вне зависимости от вида предложения (односоставное или двусоставное).

(2) Розенталь  при изложении этой темы **не объединяет односоставные предложения в одну группу,** и вам не надо этого делать!  Каждый вид предложения рассматривается в отдельности, так как везде есть свои особенности.

(3) Вы не хотите ставить в этом предложении **тире?** Хотите поставить запятую? А как вы его прочитаете, как перейдете от перечислительной интонации в первой части ко  второй части предложения? Неужели не остановитесь, не сделаете паузу?

(4) Или вы хотите поставить **только тире?**  Но такое оформление применяется для ряда однородных придаточных в препозиции http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142

У нас же более **сложная конструкция**, так как ряд придаточных отнесен к первой части  старшего  СПП (Как только встанет выбор…задайте себе вопрос...).

Именно это **место деления сложного предложения на две части** нужно обозначить  и подчеркнуть как основное, так какой же еще знак сюда может подойти, как не единый знак?

(5) Предлагайте свои варианты оформления, ссылайтесь на более подходящие  по вашему мнению правила Розенталя. Из коротких комментариев точка зрения отвечающего не всегда достаточно ясна.